# Get JSON content from incrementing URL

Tags: php, json

Below I am getting content from a single JSON file when the human visits the page:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://linkjson.com?page=1');
$decode = json_decode($file);
echo $decode;
```

When the human visits the page, how would I make the `page=` constantly increase and decode the JSON on it?

So for example when they load the page, this script would automatically run and It would then display the JSON content from EACH of the pages? Automatically add 1 to the page number every time:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://linkjson.com?page=1');
$decode = json_decode($file);
echo $decode;

$file = file_get_contents('http://linkjson.com?page=2');
$decode = json_decode($file);
echo $decode;

$file = file_get_contents('http://linkjson.com?page=3');
$decode = json_decode($file);
echo $decode;
```

But it wouldn't go past `page=2` because `page=3` is blank (has no content on it).

The amount of pages with content on it can vary, so the code would need to check if the page has content on it and if so, decode it and display it and then move onto the next page, check if it has content on it and decode it and so on.

Comment: Do you know what response the API sends if you request a nonexistent page?

Comment: @Don'tPanic i think the page will just be blank. can php check if page is blank?

Comment: I was thinking it might send a different HTTP code and that you could check for that. But checking if the result is empty should certainly be possible as well.

Comment: Be careful with quickly making lots of requests to a site. You can get blocked from some sites for doing this. You could check and see if they have an option to get unpaginated results instead.